# How to add a dropdown to a column in JQGrid in ASP and also bind it with data values?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, webforms, jqgrid-asp.net

I need to add a drop down (select supplier) under a jqgrid column.
What should I add to the designer page and JavaScript file.
Which formatter should I use ?

Answer (score 0):

If the dropdown is in the grid view and not in edit mode, you will need to create your own custom formatter and unformat functions (formatters). Note that creating unformat is recommended.

If you use the old jqGrid <=4.7 you can look at the [documentation here](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:custom_formatter):

If you use Guriddo jqGrid you may need to [look here](http://www.guriddo.net/documentation/guriddo/javascript/user-guide/formatters/#custom-formatter)